# How to properly convert curl command to Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

I have the following CURL Command which I want to convert to Jquery ajax but it alerts error **Cannot get data**

In the browser console. it shows error **401 Unathourized**

I tried leveraging solution found here [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077186/converting-curl-command-to-ajax) but still cannot get it to work

```
curl -X POST https://developer.expert.ai/oauth2/token \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
    -d '{
  "username": "yourusername",
  "password": "yourpassword"
}'
```

**Here is the coding so far**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://developer.expert.ai/oauth2/token",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
    },
    type: 'POST',
crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
data: JSON.stringify({
        'username': 'api username goes here',
        'password': 'api password goes here'
    }),
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the actual error passed to your `error` callback? `error: (_, ...err) => { console.error("Cannot get data", ...err); }` would tell you a lot more about what went wrong. You could also use your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request and response (if any)

Comment: @Phil thanks for getting back to me. I check network tab. I can see 2 url 
**index.html** which contains the ajax-jquery code  and **https://developer.expert.ai/oauth2/token** which displays result token.

Please what do I do. I need to get the **result token alerted or printed on index.html** page

Comment: What about the _Console_ tab, any errors reported there? What about the changes I suggested you make to your `error` callback? Errors don't just happen silently. Please also consult [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=text%20to%20xml.-,error,Type%3A%20Function(%20jqXHR%20jqXHR%2C%20String%20textStatus%2C%20String%20errorThrown%20),-A%20function%20to)

Comment: Thank you so much. I change  `dataType: 'json',` to  `dataType: 'html'`, and it works

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved by changing dataType Parameter from json to html as per
`dataType: 'json',` to  `dataType: 'html'`, and it works